# storing value persistently in html (javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have an android app in which I use a webview and inside webview, I load a html file.

Inside, the html file, i need to persistently store a value, so that I can use that value next time when I use the app. Because of some limitation, I cannot bring that value to android side and save it in shared preferences.

I tried using localStorage, but it did not work. Can someone please help me out with this.

Inside html, I am using javascript.

I am very new to html and javascript and do not not know much about it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you set settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); on your webview?

Comment: @Muthu.. Thanks for commenting. No I did not. I will try it and then let you know.

Comment: @Muthu.. after setting it, using localStorage worked for me. Thanks a lot. It you can move your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `setDomStorageEnabled(true)` to enable localStorage for WebView